# React static deployment renders an empty page - React, Docker, NGINX, k8s Deployment

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, nginx, dockerfile, create-react-app

I started a react project using `create-react-app` and need to deploy it on our Kubernetes cluster. I am using Docker to create an image that runs `npm run build` and copies the build files to `nginx`. After deploying to a kubernetes cluster, the ingress endpoint renders a blank white empty page, no 404 errors. Here are some details:

On inspect element the page shows script tags within the  tag with the
`<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.581a2f56.js"></script>` and
`<link href="/static/css/main.9b9c3870.css" rel="stylesheet">`
resources, however, the body contains empty root div `<div id="root"></div>`.
All HTTP calls return 200 status. All webpage routes lead to the same blank empty page.

NGINX Conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    
    location / {
        index index.html index.htm
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# Name the node stage "builder"
FROM node:14 AS builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/

RUN npm run build

# nginx stage for serving content
FROM nginx:1.15

# Set working directory to nginx asset directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy static assets from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
COPY --from=builder /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80

# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I tried the following steps as seen in many other stackoverflow answers:

1. `homepage` in package.json with values "https://companyendpoint.com" or "."
2. react-router basename with values `{process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`, "/", "/React"
3. Using HashRouter compared to BrowserRouter
4. Different configurations for nginx.conf